# Cannot publish to github package registry from travis: 401 unauthorized despite including github personal access token

Tags: node.js, git, github, travis-ci, lerna

I'm trying to publish a package to the github package registry from Travis CI. Everything seems to work fine (build and tests succeed), but when it tries to publish, I'm getting a 401 error. I've added my github personal access token as a secure env var in the travis config, and I'm manually overriding the root `.npmrc` with an npmrc that includes the github registry and the access token, but I'm still getting permission issues. How am I supposed to grant lerna/npm permission to publish a github package?

Here is my `.travis.yml`

```
env:
  global:
    secure: "my encrypted GH_TOKEN value (github personal access token with package registry permissions)"
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "12"
cache:
  directories:
    - "node_modules"
before_install:
  - echo "@my-org:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=\${GH_TOKEN}" > .npmrc
install:
  - npm ci
  - npm run bootstrap
script:
  - npm run test
  - npm run build
deploy:
  provider: script
  script: "npm run publish"
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    node: "12"
    tags: true
```

When the travis deploy runs, it errors with this:

```
> lerna publish from-git --yes --npm-tag beta

WARN deprecated --npm-tag has been renamed --dist-tag

lerna notice cli v3.20.2

lerna info ci enabled

Found 1 package to publish:

 - @my-org/example-pkg => 1.0.2-beta.8

lerna info auto-confirmed 

lerna info publish Publishing packages to npm...

lerna notice Skipping all user and access validation due to third-party registry

lerna notice Make sure you're authenticated properly ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

lerna WARN ENOLICENSE Package @my-org/example-pkg is missing a license.

lerna WARN ENOLICENSE One way to fix this is to add a LICENSE.md file to the root of this repository.

lerna WARN ENOLICENSE See https://choosealicense.com for additional guidance.

lerna WARN lifecycle Skipping root "prepublish" because it has already been called

lerna http fetch PUT 401 https://npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=[secure]/@my-org%2fexample-pkg 153ms

lerna ERR! E401 Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="GitHub Package Registry"

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! ts-utilities@1.0.0 publish: `lerna publish from-git --yes --npm-tag beta`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the ts-utilities@1.0.0 publish script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /home/travis/.npm/_logs/2020-02-25T19_46_08_862Z-debug.log

Script failed with status 1

failed to deploy
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [Found this](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2408) - not sure if it applies to you, though.

Comment: What scopes does your token have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue ended up being I needed two lines in my `.npmrc` file. One to associate org `@my-org` with the github package registry: And one to provide an auth token for the github package registry. So the whole `.npmrc` looks like this:

```
@my-org:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${GITHUB_TOKEN}
```

Then I was able to just set the `GITHUB_TOKEN` environmental variable to my github personal access token (with package read permissions) and then I was able to run `npm install @my-org/example-pkg`.